# Original click once update folder location

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I have taken over a click once project from a prior developer.  How do I find out where his click once update folder was?  The properties of the deployed apps only show where the appdata folder is.  I need to know the original update location on the click once server so I can redeploy there, but the location that is stored in the project properties is wrong (as are all of the application configuration values) so I must have an old set of source code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a shot in the dark, but if you have access to a machine that already has the application installed on it and if the application was configured to check for updates before running, you may be able to see the updates location within the app's CDF-MS file installed on that PC. The CDF-MS file is a binary file but you should be able to use STRINGS.exe or visually inspect it to find the `beforeApplicationStartup` or `deploymentProvider` value inside the file.

The file is likely located in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\RANDOM.STR\RANDOM.STR\manifests`